# Detecting collision with color on a canvas in HTML5+JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm searching for a way in JavaScript how I can detect if an `object` like this:

```
var box = {
    x: 5,
    y: 19,
    width: 10,
    height: 5,
    draw: function(ctx){...draw Box on context "ctx"},
    touchingColor: function(ctx,color){...}
}
```

So basically what I'm looking for is a function touchingColor, that returns `true` if my `box` is touching the specified color in the specified context.

Is there a way to accomplish that, or do I need to keep track of the things I drawed on the canvas?

Comment: Best option is to keep track of what you draw on the canvas as getting pixel data for an area and then finding if any of those pixels are a colour is oh so sloooowwww..... and next to impossible if you add backgrounds, foregrounds, filters, composite operations, shadows etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a way to solve this issue :) Hopefully it helps someone...

```
var box = {
    x: 5,
    y: 19,
    width: 10,
    height: 5,
    draw: function(ctx){...draw Box on context "ctx"},
    touchingColor: function(ctx,r,g,b){
        var data = ctx.getImageData(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
            if(
                data[i+0]==r&&
                data[i+1]==g&&
                data[i+2]==b
            ){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: use `ctx.getImageData(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height).data`